When using try-runtime to test migration and upgrade, I encountered an error related to `CurrentSlot`
It's version: try-runtime-core 0.8.0.
The substrate framework version I use: branch = "polkadot-v1.10.1".
The command I used when executing try-runtime:
try-runtime --runtime ./cess_node_runtime.wasm on-runtime-upgrade --blocktime 6000 live --uri wss://testnet-rpc.cess.network/ws/.
Then I encountered the following error:
[2024-10-31T02:42:48Z INFO  remote-ext] ‍ scraping child-tree data from 4 top keys
[2024-10-31T02:42:49Z INFO  remote-ext] initialized state externalities with storage root 0xb7a77884e8c755ada1c472b3d4913ea6c257ef432ed023719cd24e2ed112816d and state_version V0
[2024-10-31T02:42:49Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] Original runtime [Name: RuntimeString::Owned("cess-node")] [Version: 122] [Code hash: 0xb0c2...72b3]
[2024-10-31T02:42:49Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] New runtime      [Name: RuntimeString::Owned("cess-node")] [Version: 123] [Code hash: 0xdfa1...3575]
[2024-10-31T02:42:54Z INFO  try_runtime_core::common::empty_block::production] Producing new empty block at height 1303731
[2024-10-31T02:42:55Z ERROR runtime] panicked at /home/ytqaljn/Desktop/cess/crates/rrsc/pallet/src/lib.rs:906:9:
    Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`
thread 'main' panicked at cli/main.rs:326:10:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Input("failed to execute 'BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic': Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x7308ab - cess_node_runtime.wasm!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x63bd6f - cess_node_runtime.wasm!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hd243da3e585de500\n    2: 0x466eab - cess_node_runtime.wasm!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::h07169926b3567de5\n    3: 0x188618 - cess_node_runtime.wasm!environmental::local_key::LocalKey<T>::with::h548adb56d1f64eff\n    4: 0x29f7a - cess_node_runtime.wasm!<cess_node_runtime::RuntimeCall as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h1cf4fa39a94d2683\n    5: 0x33a7e - cess_node_runtime.wasm!<cess_node_runtime::RuntimeCall as sp_runtime::traits::Dispatchable>::dispatch::hd1cd077e1b1d352d\n    6: 0x51d72c - cess_node_runtime.wasm!<fp_self_contained::checked_extrinsic::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId,Call,Extra,SelfContainedSignedInfo> as sp_runtime::traits::Applyable>::apply::hc714dc7b0dd13bba\n    7: 0x103f78 - cess_node_runtime.wasm!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::apply_extrinsic::h82f7bffe15cdf54e\n    8: 0x12f36e - cess_node_runtime.wasm!BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic")
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

The code snippet mentioned in the error:
impl<T: Config> OnTimestampSet<T::Moment> for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_timestamp_set(moment: T::Moment) {
        let slot_duration = Self::slot_duration();
        assert!(!slot_duration.is_zero(), "RRSC slot duration cannot be zero.");

        let timestamp_slot = moment / slot_duration;
        let timestamp_slot = Slot::from(timestamp_slot.saturated_into::<u64>());

        assert!(
            CurrentSlot::<T>::get() == timestamp_slot,
            "Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`"
        );
    }
}


Suggest using code block instead of image.

Okay, I have modified it

@AurevoirXavier

How many seconds blocktime does your chain have? Could be this: https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli/issues/101
Is the code open-source? Then I can check it locally.

Can you also try version 0.7.0 please? We added lots of stuff in the last version, possibly something broke there.

Okay, I will try 0.7.0.

@OliverTale-Yazdi Our blocktime is 6000
